# How I can render a form with multiple choices field in template side?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to render a form in template, on of this form field has multiple entries to select(like combobox), I can show form with default django {{ form }} but in custom bootstrap form no idea about it, can anyone help me?
this is my form:

`

```
class CreateClubForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=127)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ClubCategories.objects.all())
```

`

I tried forloop to passing data to dropdown select but it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

guys I did it in currect way, it was forloop but in simple way

first I created a select by key name "category"

```
<select class="form-select"  name="category">                                    
    #optione here
</select>
```

then I tried to render my options by forloop inside instead #options here:

```
{% for field in form.category %}
       <option selected>{{ field }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

it worked in best way

Answer (score 0):

you need to manually render the form fields in the template.
your HTML file should looks something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Name:</label>
        {{ form.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.category.id_for_label }}">Category:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="{{ form.category.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.category.html_name }}">
            {% for category in form.category.field.queryset %}
                <option value="{{ category.pk }}" {% if category.pk == form.category.value() %}selected{% endif %}>{{ category.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`form.category` field is manually rendered as a select dropdown.

`{% for category in form.category.field.queryset %}` iterates over the queryset to create options for the dropdown and it sets the `selected` attribute for the option that value matches the current value of the field.

make sure to include the necessary bootstrap css and JavaScript files in your template.

I hope this helps you.